# Fifth partition

Tags: dual-boot, windows, gparted, partitioning

I'm trying to install to my Dell Latitude E6540 ubuntu 14.04 and windows 8.1. The problem is that I want to make a fifth partition for storage.
The 1st partition is for ubuntu os. The 2nd is for swap(extended).
The 3rd is something windows reserve for the system(I don't know why).
The 4th is for windows os.
All of them are primary, So I cannot use the unallocated space for anything, because gparted tells me that I'm only allowed to have 4 primary partitions.
How can I fix it? I want to see storage partition from both os.

Comment: format as NTFS file system type and select "logical" instead of "primary". and NFTS partition will detect from both OS.

Answer (score 1):

You are only allowed four (4) Primary partitions. If you have to create a fifth (5) partition, then you will have to create it as logical partition. This option is available in Gparted.

Comment: The extended partition that acts as the container for all the logical partitions counts as one of the primary partitions. Your current extended only contains swap but you can shrink space next to it and expand the extended to make more logical partitions. Windows usually installs to two partitions. One small boot partition and the main install. Small boot partition has the repair console and allows you to separately encrypt the main partition if desired. Usually better to have Windows before the extended. Be sure to back up partition table after any change if Windows is after extended.